# How to read audio (mp3) tags (Duration and Subtitle), when I use TagLib?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mp3, id3

I am using TagLib (UltraID3Lib couldn't read every MP3 file). Maybe TagLib will do.
And I couldn't find properties like Subtitle or Duration or Time?

How do I find this kind of tags?

Example:
"Ondertitel" means Subtitle

[image]
**The second question is:
And how can I find the tag Subtitle by using TagLib?**

Comment: Are you sure those tags exist in the files you're testing?

Comment: Subtitle and Duration do exist for mp3 files. A lot of songs have subtitles. And if you opens the properties of a audio file, the second property is subtitle, between title and command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way, you can get the duration:

```
var file = TagLib.File.Create(@"xyz.mp3");

Console.WriteLine(file.Properties.Duration);
```

Comment: Thank you! And do you how to get Subtitles from the files?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think TagLib# cannot read subtitles.

Comment: Do the tags consist of a key ["Subtitle"] with a value ["part II"] in the files? And how can you read that in files?

Comment: Can you provide an example file?

Comment: I've added the properties of an example.