# How to display the maximum duration of a song using timespan?

Tags: c#, wpf, timespan

In my music player, there are 2 labels.

Label 1 is for showing the progress time:

```
lblTime.Content = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sliProgress.Value).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

And label 2 is for showing the maximum duration of a song:

```
lblTime2.Content = TimeSpan.MaxValue.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Label 1 was working well from start playing and when I move the slider. But the label 2 somehow doesn't show anything. I have tried using Properties.Duration syntax in taglib-sharp. But for me, it show too much details, since I just want show the minutes and the seconds, not the hours even the miliseconds.

What should I do to fix the label 2?

Comment: TimeSpan.MaxValue is a constant value and represents the maximum value a TimeSpan can handle.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So, what must I correct to make label 2 can show the maximum duration of a playing song (ex. 05:42)?

Comment: Get the duration information from the song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suddenly found an idea about using ToString syntax to taglib, similar to as I did for label 1. Now it works as I expected, displaying just only minutes and seconds.

This is the code I use:

```
lblTime2.Content=tagFile.Properties.Duration.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to retrieve the duration from the song (or rather file), see this
 SO post; [How to read audio (mp3) tags (Duration and Subtitle), when I use TagLib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089205/how-to-read-audio-mp3-tags-duration-and-subtitle-when-i-use-taglib)

According to the taglib documentation (which I find a bit confusing) - see [this API page](http://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1MPEG_1_1Properties.html#a974d5611f66e157f9e8674d485ee7377) - the `lengthInSeconds` property returns an integer.

So, to display it on your label, try this.

```
var vFile = TagLib.File.Create(@"xyz.mp3");
int vDuration = vFile.Properties.lengthInSeconds;
lblTime2.Content = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(vDuration).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

(All untested!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately, I got an error which said that Properties doesn't contain a definiton for lengthInSeconds and no extension method lengthInSeconds accepting a first argument of type Properties could be found.

Comment: I have answer my own questions below. Thanks for your inspiration.

Comment: Yes, like I said, the API descriptions are somewhat confusing and I didn't have time to go through it all!  At least you got it all sorted out now.